# Boot is running fairly slow

Tags: uefi, bios

I have completely reformatted my HD and made various partitions.  My BIOS is in Legacy mode so I created a partition for Ubuntu to boot (sda1).  A pop up message appeared when I went to save that asked me to create an EFI partition for Ubuntu to boot.  I did and now it is taking quite a while to load.  I ran boot repair.  Should I delete the EFI partition?

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6764562

Also, I set my boot to "Ubuntu" in my bios.

Answer (score 0):

You are *not* booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. You have no BIOS-mode boot loader installed in the disk's MBR, but you *do* have EFI-mode boot loaders in the EFI System Partition (ESP; `/dev/sda3` on your computer). The fact that your firmware is set to enable BIOS/CSM/legacy mode is irrelevant; on most computers, that option just opens the door for such boots, but doesn't force the computer to boot in that way.

***Do not*** delete the ESP. Your boot loaders reside there, so deleting that partition will render the computer unbootable!

Your description is unclear about what's causing the sluggish boot. Elaboration on this point is required. For instance, does it take a long time for GRUB to appear, or does the system pause for a long time after GRUB appears? It might be helpful to use GRUB to edit the boot options so as to remove the `quiet splash` kernel options. This should result in a more verbose boot, which may provide a clue about what's causing the slowdown -- you might see errors or be able to notice a message that precedes or immediately follows an inordinate pause. Alternatively, type `dmesg > foo.txt` and then upload the contents of `foo.txt` to a pastebin site and post the resulting URL here.